# How can I check if two object's attributes are similar except for one attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

In the two objects below, I want to compare their equality by testing all their attributes (name, modifiers, price) EXCEPT for one attribute (quantity).

As in the example below, if I simply compared the two objects (`Obj A` & `Obj B`) they would be equal in every case, except for their quantity attribute. I'm simply looking to exclude quantity when doing a comparison between the two objects.

**Obj A**

```
{
   name: "Bud Lite",
   price: 399,
   modifiers: null,
   quantity: 2,   
}
```

**Obj B**

```
{
   name: "Bud Lite",
   price: 399,
   modifiers: null,
   quantity: 1,   
}
```

**Here's how I'm currently doing it:**

```
if (JSON.stringify(ObjA) === JSON.stringify(ObjB)) {
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Just don't compare quantity? How are you comparing them now?

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify` to compare objects is very fragile and unreliable. You have to perform the comparison attribute-by-attribute according to your own requirements for equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `spread (...)` before to exclude the quantity or any other properties

```js
const { quantity: quantitya, ...a } = {
   name: "Bud Lite",
   price: 399,
   modifiers: null,
   quantity: 2,   
}

const { quantity: quantityb, ...b } = {
   name: "Bud Lite",
   price: 399,
   modifiers: null,
   quantity: 1,   
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b))
```

Comment: or the other way around: `if (JSON.stringify({...a, quantity: 0})...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an omit function prior to comparing.

```js
const omit = (ks) => o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(([k]) => !ks.includes(k)))

const withoutQuantity = omit(["quantity"]);

const equal = (a, b) => {
    const ae = Object.entries(a);
    const be = Object.entries(b);
    return ae.length === be.length && ae.every(([k, x]) => x === b[k]);
}

equal(withoutQuantity(objA), withoutQuantity(objB));
```

It would not be hard to compose together an object equality function that ignores provided properties either.

Comment: what is `equal()` though?

Comment: edited to include implementation of `equal`

Answer (score 1):

I have written one general function to check 2 objects having an option to exclude specific number of attributes.

All you need to use like this:

```
ObjA = { name: "Bud Lite", price: 399, quantity: 2, someAttr : "abcd" }
ObjB = { name: "Bud Lite", price: 399, quantity: 1, someAttr : "abcdef" }

const isEqual = compareObjects(ObjA,ObjB,['quantity','someAttr'])
console.log(isEqual) //true
// Pass the attributes in the array to exlude while comparing
```

The function which does the trick without any modification is:

```
export function compareObjects(obj1, obj2, excludedProperty) {
const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1).filter(
    (key) => !excludedProperty.includes(key)
);
const keys2 = Object.keys(obj2).filter(
    (key) => !excludedProperty.includes(key)
);

if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
    return false;
}

for (let key of keys1) {
    if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

}

Comment: that was helpful, however I would suggest one edit if you want to check if the data is exactly the same, as the```obj1[key] !== obj2[key]``` always returned true in my nested object - so I replaced that line with
```if (JSON.stringify(obj1[key]) !== JSON.stringify(obj2[key]))```